# Spring Boot + Security OAuth2.0 Client with Custom Provider

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2, oauth2client

I am creating a OAuth2.0 client for a custom OAuth2 provider in Spring Boot + Security (version 5) application.

Below is the `application.properties` which has all the configuration and there is no additional configuration class in my project.

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.xxxxxxxxx.client-id=XXXXXXXXXX
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.xxxxxxxxx.client-secret=XXXXXXXXXX
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.xxxxxxxxx.scope=openid
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.xxxxxxxxx.redirect-uri-template=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/xxxxxxxxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.xxxxxxxxx.client-name=xxxxxxxxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.xxxxxxxxx.provider=xxxxxxxxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.xxxxxxxxx.client-authentication-method=basic
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.xxxxxxxxx.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.xxxxxxxxx.authorization-uri=https://api.xxxxxxxxx.com/authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.xxxxxxxxx.token-uri=https://api.xxxxxxxxx.com/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.xxxxxxxxx.user-info-uri=https://api.xxxxxxxxx.com/userinfo?schema=openid
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.xxxxxxxxx.user-name-attribute=name
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.xxxxxxxxx.user-info-authentication-method=header
```

When i hit `http://localhost:8080/` it redirects properly to provider's login page and after successful login it redirects back to my application.

Now the problem is when it redirects then it shows below error message.
[image]

I have googled for this error but didn't get any proper answer. Also, the OAuth2 provider didn't share such URL.

After research I came to know that i need to set below property. Should it be provided by Auth Provider?
`spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.pepstores.jwk-set-uri`

What exactly I am missing here in configuration?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally, the problem is solved. I just need to configure the jwk URI which should be provided by the Auth provider. 
Below the final configuration for customer Auth Provider.

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.xxxxxxxxx.client-id=XXXXXXXXXX
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.xxxxxxxxx.client-secret=XXXXXXXXXX
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.xxxxxxxxx.scope=openid
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.xxxxxxxxx.redirect-uri-template=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/xxxxxxxxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.xxxxxxxxx.client-name=xxxxxxxxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.xxxxxxxxx.provider=xxxxxxxxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.xxxxxxxxx.client-authentication-method=basic
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.xxxxxxxxx.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.xxxxxxxxx.authorization-uri=https://api.xxxxxxxxx.com/authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.xxxxxxxxx.token-uri=https://api.xxxxxxxxx.com/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.xxxxxxxxx.user-info-uri=https://api.xxxxxxxxx.com/userinfo?schema=openid
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.xxxxxxxxx.user-name-attribute=name
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.xxxxxxxxx.user-info-authentication-method=header
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.xxxxxxxxx.jwk-set-uri=https://api.xxxxxxxxx.com/jwks
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you receive JWT in client application, you need to verify the signature of JWT. To verify the signature you need public key of Auth provider. As per OAuth specifications, Auth provider can expose the public key through a URI and client can use this URI to get the public key to validate the JWT. This is what is missing in your configuration.